# Ruby Gem server not serving gems?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, teamcity

I am trying to make a new acceptance agent for teamcity...I followed this article http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/18...

I created a website in IIS called gemserver and having a port 910. it has gems folder which has ancient gems like activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-1.0.0.9250...

I don't know the mime-type for .gem extension so I just put application/x-ruby-gem. Although manually when I put machinename:910/gems/Gem_Name I am able to download it.

but when i use bundle install it gives below error

```
Fetching source index for http://gems.github.com/
Fetching source index for my server url
Could not reach rubygems repository http://gems.github.com/, my server url:
910/, http://rubygems.org/
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Could not find gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (= 1.0.0.9250, runtime)' in a
ny of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
```

Please find below Gemfile.

```
source "http://computerName:910/"
source :gemcutter

gem 'rake', '0.8.7'
gem 'cucumber', '0.6.2'
gem 'watir', '1.6.5'
gem 'activerecord', '2.3.8'
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', '1.0.0.9250'
gem 'rspec', '1.3.0'
gem 'parseexcel', '0.5.2'
gem 'win32-api', '1.4.5'
gem 'nokogiri', '1.4.1'
gem 'win32-eventlog', '0.5.2'
gem 'win32console'
```

Comment: Why is it trying to access http://gems.github.com ?

Comment: I thought it will pick the gem from there as well.#

Comment: It will go through the sources listed in the Gemfile, I can not tell from the error message if it is correctly looking at your local gem server.

Comment: should i remove all others and check with only my gem server? sounds cool. let me try

Comment: If you could, then update the question with your Gemfile and error.

Comment: sorry for the delay bit above is the gemfile and error.

Comment: Have you tried with the simple option `gem_server`? that might help debug where the connection issue is. It is still failing to find rubygems which is odd.

Comment: I'm guessing problem from message `Could not reach rubygems repository`, it's network problem. If you do `telnet computerName 910`, what result do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use the ip address instead of computername and see if that fixes your 504 problem
2. Now try to update your gems, if you get a 404 error when trying to access a folder called /quick then run the generate_index command with the --legacy option

> ```
> gem generate_index --legacy
> ```

1. Add .rz mimetype to your IIS so that it can serve the rzip files. In IIS mime types, add the following mapping:

> .rz -> application/x-rzip

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know the mime-type for .gem extension so I just put application/x-ruby-gem. Although manually when I put machinename:910/gems/Gem_Name I am able to download it.

Your gem client is complaining that the **source index** can't be reached, not the gem itself.

In the article you linked to, item 4.2.4 instructs:

> Run the `generate_index` gem command in order to generate the `yaml` and `yaml.Z` files needed by the RubyGems client.

Make sure `generate_index` created the `yaml` and `yaml.Z` files in your gems directory. Check if they are accessible. This is the source index that your gems client is looking for.

For example, GitHub's gem source index file is located here: http://gems.github.com/gems/yaml

Comment: generate_index is not generating yaml and yaml.z I am not sure why is that but according to rubygem support it is not needed anymore :s
http://help.rubygems.org/discussions/problems/1422-gem-server-is-not-serving-gems

Comment: Seems like the guide is outdated. However, according to that discussion, you [don't have ruby installed on your gem server](http://help.rubygems.org/discussions/problems/1422-gem-server-is-not-serving-gems#comment_21503365). Is this true?

Comment: Yes, I have already a folder structure on that server and no ruby installed. I do this on my local machine and copy the files to gem server

Comment: There's your problem. The gem server is not IIS but `gem` itself (invoked by the `gem server` command) which is ruby-based. If you don't have ruby installed, it obviously won't work.

Comment: so you mean to say if I install Ruby this should solve the problem? let me try and comment back.

Comment: If you can get Ruby + [RubyGems](http://rubygems.org/pages/download) installed, configured and running (with `gem server`), it should work.  Forget about IIS; you don't need it to serve gems.

Comment: I am right at the end I believe...According to ruby staff files were correctly generated but I am getting error: 504 Gateway Time-out
Error fetching remote data:             bad response Gateway Time-out 504 (http://WGB01AP1128:910/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

Comment: I can download manually though the above file which it is trying to download but when i do gem install -V activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-1.0.0.9250 --source http://WGB01AP1128:910 it gives 504 gateway in cmd. any idea?

Comment: could you list the steps how to conigure using gem server?

Comment: Start [here](http://guides.rubygems.org/run-your-own-gem-server/). Ask a new question if you need further help.